# how to find nfs folder of a mounted directory in shell script

Tags: linux, nfs

I am trying to find solution to the linux command.

I have a folder and that is mounted to a nfs share.

folder name is /root/user1 (lets say)

if i do 
$ df  /root/users1
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
server-1:/root/master_folder
                      22222  456324  3167  2% /root/users1

From this command i am only interested in nfs server name , nfs location which in this case is ,
server-1:/root/master_folder

How can i achieve this in bash scripts ?
Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try

`df /root/user1 | sed '1d' - | cut -d" " -f1`